# How to apply intervention analysis to time series?

Tags: r, time-series, intervention-analysis

I have weekly sales data for a restaurant, with 113 observations, and every year in January, sales drop significantly and then recover after two or four weeks. I applied a SARIMA model with auto-arima in R, but when I evaluate my model, I realize that the residuals are not constant and not normally distributed. Box-Cox Transformation was already used, lamba was 1.99 but it did not improve the model.

Upon reviewing a time series text, I learned that I need to create a dummy variable. I looked at the observations where the pattern breaks in January and classified them as "1", with the others as zero. I estimated my model again and it resulted in a SARIMA with rgex, but when I reviewed the residuals, I still have extremely high residuals in those periods. Residuals used to be -10000, now they are mostly -5000, so they were reduced. Do you have any suggestions? What types of interventions exist? I placed "1" for the first few weeks of January, then "0" when I see that sales have reached their normal level.
To test for stationarity, I used the Augmented Dickey-Fuller test and found that the data was not stationary. Therefore, I differenced the time series and checked for stationarity again using the ADF test.
Next, I decomposed the time series into its seasonal, trend, and residual components and plotted the results. I then fit a SARIMA model using auto.arima and checked its diagnostic tests for accuracy. Additionally, I  performed a Box-Ljung test to check for autocorrelation in the residuals and a Jarque-Bera test for normality. Box-Ljung was fine, but Jarque-Bera was not.
I then added a dummy variable for intervention analysis to account for outliers or extreme values in the data. I fit a second SARIMA model using the dummy variable and checked its diagnostic tests for accuracy. However, yI found that the variance was still high, and upon further investigation, I found that the highest residuals corresponded to the same period that I alreadt included in the dummy variable for intervention. What else could I do? any suggestion? thanks!